# Periodic Orbit using Poincare Bendixson Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system $$x' = −y + x(r^4 − 3r^2 + 1)$$ $$y' = x + y(r^4 − 3r^2 +1)$$ where $$r^2=x^2 + y^2$$
Question: Show that $r' < 0$ on the circle $r = 1$ and $r' > 0$ on the circle $r = 2$. Use the Poincare Bendixon theorem and the fact that the only equilibrium point of this system is at the origin to show that there is a periodic orbit in the annular region $$A = {x ∈ R^2 : 1 < |x| < 2}$$
Why does the periodic orbit not have any point common to the boundary of A?

I was able to do the first part and found that $r' < 0$ on the circle $r = 1$ and $r' > 0$ on the circle $r = 2$. I am currently stuck on how to use the Poincare Bendixon Theorem to show that there is an orbit in that given annular region.

Poincare-Bendixon Theorem- Suppose that $f ∈ C^1 (E)$ where $E$ is an open subset of $R^2$ and that $x'=f(x)$ has a trajectory $Γ$ with $Γ^+$ contained in a compact subset $F$ of $E$. Then if $ω(Γ)$ contains no critical points of $x'=f(x)$, $ω(Γ)$ is a periodic orbit of $x'=f(x)$

Comment: So, what's exactly your question here?

Comment: I want to know how to Use the Poincare Bendixon theorem and the fact that the only equilibrium point of this system is at the origin to show that there is a periodic orbit in the annular region A

Comment: Oh, then it is not so hard to explain. To apply PB Theorem as it is stated here, you have to revert time, and this is equivalent to reverting the direction of the vector field. After that vector field starts to pointing _inward_ at the annulus boundary. It means that now any trajectory doesn't go outside of the annulus. So, for any $\Gamma$ it's $\Gamma^{+}$ is contained in the annulus closure. You start considering $\omega(\Gamma)$ and see that all equilibria are outside of the annulus. So, $\omega(\Gamma)$ can be only a periodic orbit.

Comment: Sure this is not $r^2 =x^2 + y^2$?

Comment: Sorry you are correct I edited it

Comment: And what happened when you computed $r'$, using $rr'=xx'+yy'$?